# How to pass value using ImageButton to update database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controlparameter

I having problem when I try to pass value from ImageButton to a controlparameter, then the update command can retrieve the value from control parameter to execute update statement.

I want to pass value Status=1 when ImageButton APPROVE is clicked, else pass value Status=2 when ImageButton REJECT is clicked.

Where and how should I assign value Status?
When I run my code, I receive this error : Must declare the scalar variable "@Status".

Or any recommendation to pass the value Status?

My ImageButton:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="APPROVE" CommandName="update" 
ImageUrl="~/images/accept.png"
OnClientClick="if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to approve this booking?')) return false;" />
</ItemTemplate>


<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="REJECT" CommandName="update"
ImageUrl="~/images/reject.png"
OnClientClick="if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to reject this booking?')) return false;" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

My UPDATE statement

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [bookingschedule] SET status=@Status WHERE [bookingScheduleID] = @bookingScheduleID"
```

My ControlParameter

```
<UpdateParameters>                            
<asp:Parameter Name="bookingScheduleID" Type="Int32" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="Status" ControlID="APPROVE"  Type="Int32" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="Status" ControlID="REJECT"  Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

A button does not have a value in html and thus you can't use it in the ControlParameter declaration.  One solution is to make a hidden textbox on the form.  Lets call it "StatusType".

```
<input type="hidden" name="StatusType" value="0">
```

Now, in the "OnClientClick" of each of the buttons; assign the StatusType's value to either 1 or 2 (or whatever your defined status codes are).

```
OnClientClick="if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to reject this booking?')) {
    return;
}
else {
    $('#StatusType').val(0);
}"
```

Then use "StatusType" in the ControlParameter.

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="Status" ControlID="StatusType"  Type="Int32" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [CommandArgument property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandargument.aspx) of the ImageButton?

From MSDN:

> Sometimes, multiple ImageButton controls are related and share the same value for the CommandName property, such as Sort. Use this property to supplement the CommandName property with additional information about the command to perform, such as Ascending. The values of the CommandName and CommandArgument properties are typically used in the OnCommand event handler to determine the action to perform when the ImageButton control is clicked.

```
<asp:ImageButton id="imagebutton1" runat="server"
       AlternateText="Sort Ascending"
       ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg"
       OnCommand="ImageButton_Command"
       CommandName="Sort"
       CommandArgument="Ascending"/>
```

Comment: I did try this and other solution, just i always receive error : Must declare the scalar variable "@Status"
Seem like the value just not passing